# How to load javascript dynamically in angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have pages with different Js and CSS  in **angularJS**. So I need to load as per page.
So what should I do.

**etc.**

*for one page load two JS.*

*for second page load two JS.*

*for third page load one JS.*

...

How to load JS as per page?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939913/single-page-application-load-js-file-dynamically-based-on-partial-view

Answer (score 1):

Yes you load javascript files asynchronously in other words ,you want lazy loading in your project,There are various methods to do it
like: 
a.reqiurejs
b.ocLazyLoad.js

please read this docs ,It may help you a lot

For ocLazyLoad.js:-https://oclazyload.readme.io/

For reqiurejs:-http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html
I would personally prefre reqiurejs because it will handle dependecies very efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly what you need is some kind of Lazy Loading. There are different ways to achieve this in AngularJS 1.x and from what I've heard Angular 2.x will provide its own way to lazy load.

Check this approach: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-simple-lazy-loaded-angular-module-syntax-with-oclazyload