# Load Controller Based on View

Tags: angularjs

I have an app in Angular which will become large over time and I do not want users to load all the controllers upfront inside the `index.html`. To overcome some scaling issues I would like to load the controller for a given view when the user visits that given view. I do not want to statically define the controller and view in my `router.js` but rather source them dynamically. My `router.js` looks as follows:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            controller: 'HomeController',
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
        })
        .when('/portfolio/:page', {
            controller: 'TopLevelController',
            templateUrl: function(params){ return 'views/portfolio/'+params.page+'.html';}
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
});
```

There will be a large number of view inside the `portfolio` folder and each view will have its own controller. Each view is very different due to visualisations and the usage of directives.

One solution I thought would help was found on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939913/single-page-application-load-js-file-dynamically-based-on-partial-view), where I have a top level controller and then source the required JS through this controller.

My top level controller looks like:

```
app.controller('TopLevelController', ['$scope', '$route', '$controller', function($scope, $route, $controller) {    
    $scope.loadScript = function(url, type, charset) {
        if (type===undefined) type = 'text/javascript';
        if (url) {
            var script = document.querySelector("script[src*='"+url+"']");
            if (!script) {
                var heads = document.getElementsByTagName("head");
                if (heads && heads.length) {
                    var head = heads[0];
                    if (head) {
                        script = document.createElement('script');
                        script.setAttribute('src', url);
                        script.setAttribute('type', type);
                        if (charset) script.setAttribute('charset', charset);
                        head.appendChild(script);
                    }
                }
            }
            return script;
        }
    };

    var controllerToLoad = $route.current.params.page+'Controller.js';

    $scope.loadScript('js/controllers/portfolio/'+controllerToLoad, 'text/javascript', 'utf-8');

}]);
```

An example view in side portfolio is 'PDB.html' and looks like as follows:

```
<html>
<body ng-controller="PDBController">
{{test}}
Static Text
</body>
</html>
```

The `PDBController` looks like:

```
app.controller('PDBController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.test = "inside PDBController";
    console.log("i exist");
}]);
```

But when I visit then view all I get is:
[image]

I do not see the text "inside PDBController" nor do I see "i exists" in the console output. Could anyone point out where I cam going wrong or provide a solution?

Comment: There is no lazy load of component scripts built into angular. Need third party modules to do it

Comment: The controllers are not instantiated unless you add a partial with them in it. So they are not 'loaded', but you need to define them. You need a lot of controllers with tons of code to get into scaling issues.