# Add script tag inside html in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to add a script tag inside **paysucc.html** if response.statusText == "OK". How is that possible?

script:

```
<script src="https://test.oppwa.com/v1/paymentWidgets.js?checkoutId={checkoutId}"></script>
```

Where checkoutId is **response.data.id**

Payment.html:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn-normal pay-btn" ng-click="processpartners()">Pay From Processing partners</button>
```

Controller.js:

```
$scope.processpartners = function() {
        var request = $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: SITE_URL + '/api/processpartners',
            data: {
                amount: $scope.amount,
                currency: $scope.currency,
            },
        }).then(function(response) {                       
            if ((response.statusText == "OK") && (response.status == 200)) {
                $location.path(SITE_URL + '/paysucc', response.data.id).replace();
            }
        });
    };
```

routes.js:

```
 when(SITE_URL + '/paysucc', {
        templateUrl: TEMPLATE_URL + '/partials/paysucc.html',
        controller: 'PaymentsuccessController'
    })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically adding a url into a script tag in AngularJs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36311082/dynamically-adding-a-url-into-a-script-tag-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 1):

Please, try this solution may it's help you:

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.src = "http://somedomain.com/somescript";
$("head").append(s);
```