# How should I load all my javascript files that contain my controllers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular and making a small project.

For now, I have one large App.js where I define my route config and controllers and such.

In my index.html file, I link to this script file and everything works fine, I have multiple views and a small working app.

Now I would like to extract the controllers from my big javascript file, but then, what is the best way to include all those files? I do not want to have one script tag per file.

Comment: That's exactly what you should have.  Then you should use a build tool, like browserify or closure compiler, to put them back into a single file before deploying.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939913/single-page-application-load-js-file-dynamically-based-on-partial-view

Comment: ok so Angular doesn't provide an out-of-the-box way of managing these files...thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are worried about the fact that you will add the files manually over and over again, you could try to automate this process using [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) or [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) but it will take a bit of research. What I recommend, though, is using an already set-up generator with these systems in place for you. Such a generator would be the [Hottowel](https://github.com/johnpapa/generator-hottowel) generator made by John Papa, which also respect his [Angular Styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md).

Whatever you choose in the end is your preference, but I recommend looking into such generators and explore their way of doing the architecture of an Angular application and then see what suits your needs best.