# Pinterest board only works on page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, pinterest

I have a AngularJS application, which is a single page application. On each individual page a Pinterest board gets loaded, this is done through Pinterest's widget builder:

[This can be found here](https://developers.pinterest.com/tools/widget-builder/?type=board&boardHeight=240&boardWidth=400&imageWidth=80&template=custom&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pinterest.com%2Fpinterest%2Fpinstudio%2F)

It gives me the following to stick into my application:

```
<a data-pin-do="embedBoard" data-pin-board-width="400" data-pin-scale-height="240" data-pin-scale-width="80" href="https://www.pinterest.com/pinterest/pinstudio/"></a>
```

and:

```
<script async defer src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

I added this and the Pinterest board loaded, however when going to a different page, the Pinterest board wouldn't load without a page refresh, I believed this was because the script wasn't able to regenerate / or load the specific element on the page, it just didn't know it was there.

So I used the following inside of my Angular Js application in the top-level controller: ( got this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939913/single-page-application-load-js-file-dynamically-based-on-partial-view) )

```
$scope.loadScript = function(url, type, charset) {
    if (type===undefined) type = 'text/javascript';
    if (url) {
        var script = document.querySelector("script[src*='"+url+"']");
        if (!script) {
            var heads = document.getElementsByTagName("head");
            if (heads && heads.length) {
                var head = heads[0];
                if (head) {
                    script = document.createElement('script');
                    script.setAttribute('src', url);
                    script.setAttribute('type', type);
                    if (charset) script.setAttribute('charset', charset);
                    head.appendChild(script);
                }
            }
        }
        return script;
    }
};
```

I then inserted the following into my sub controller to load the script in:

```
$scope.$parent.loadScript('//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js');
```

This works correctly and adds my script to the page, but again the pinterest board wont load until refresh, I am out of ideas, I can't seem to find out why the script wont load the element until the page is refreshed.

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: This is **likely** because `embedBoard` element is not present when script gets loaded. For making Pin button on Angular app, we used `PinUtils.pinAny();` For board, you can try https://github.com/cornflourblue/angular-pinterest

Comment: Please feel free to post as an answer and i can mark as correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *likely* because `embedBoard` element is not present when script gets loaded.

In similar context, for making Pin button on Angular app, we used [`PinUtils.pinAny();`](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/widgets/save/)

For board, you can try [angular-pinterest](https://github.com/cornflourblue/angular-pinterest).