# How to get html script src value from js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

My question is about making src in html script tag dynamic. Now, I have something like this at the bottom of the html :

```
<script src="https://blabla.com/assets/jxx.js"></script>
```

In my angular js file, I've a method to return the url prefix dynamically.

```
$scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl($scope.pathPrefix + src);        
};
```

And what I want to do is transform the *src* part to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{trustSrc('/assets/jxx.js')}}"></script>
```

The prefix of the url changes depending on the environment. So I need to change it dynamically.

This method works if I put the script tag in the html's *head* portion. But mine should be outside of the head and at the bottom of the html.

What do you recommend to do this?

Comment: Not sure why you're trying to do this or how to test if my suggestion works, but have you tried ng-src instead of src: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

Comment: I don't know why you need to have it in dynamic script tag. If there is no other reason for that, you can use this Jquery function https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Comment: I came across these: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15939913/single-page-application-load-js-file-dynamically-based-on-partial-view, https://stackoverflow.com/q/12197880/angularjs-how-to-make-angular-load-script-inside-ng-include. Do either provide what you are looking for?

Comment: ng-src itself is not enough. I tried that already. But I didn't try the other solutions yet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but it can be happening because of your controller's scope.

As you are using `trustSrc`function with `$scope`in your controller, make sure that in HTML file you are using `<script></script>` in controller's scope.

Comment: I'm using it with $scope as above. The problem is if I put that last line in html *head* portion it works , but in the *body* portion it is not working. What should I do to make it work in html body, that is my question actually.